# Multiple case in update postgres

Tags: postgresql, case, postgresql-11

I need to update 2 columns in table with same conditions. I know, that each of them would take a lot of time. How can I concatenate 2 updates into 1, which can be faster?

-- first update

```
update t1
set col1 =
case when cc1  is not NULL and cc1  <> 0 then 'A'
        when cc2 is not NULL and cc2 <> 0 then 'B'
        when cc3 is not NULL and cc3 <> 0 then 'C'
       else null
end;
```

-- with same cond

```
update t1 
             set    col2 =
             case when cc1  is not NULL and cc1  <> 0 then 'qwe rty'
                     when cc2 is not NULL and cc2 <> 0 then 'qzaz wsx'
                     when cc3 is not NULL and cc3 <> 0 then 'zxcv asdf'
              else 'pl ok'
             end;
```

-- my effort to concatenate, dont work

```
update  t1
             set    (col1, col2)  =
             (select c1, c2 from
              (select case when t2.cc1  is not NULL and  t2.cc1  <> 0 then 'A' as c1,  'qwe rty' as  c2
                     when t2.cc2 is not NULL and t2.cc2 <> 0 then ('B', 'qaz wsx')
                     when t2.cc3 is not NULL and t2.cc3 <> 0 then ('C', ' zxcv asdf')
              else (null, 'pl ok')
             end 
             from t1 as t2 where t1.key_column1 = t2.key_column1 and t1.key_column2 = t2.key_column2 and t1.key_column3 = t2.key_column3) f)

       ;
```

Comment: Why not just `set col1=…, col2=…` like a regular update?

Comment: Dont catch ... I want to compare case and use all three conditions once, not twice

Comment: Have you tried it and determined that the database engine doesn’t optimize it that way and it’s a problem?

Comment: I know the size of table t1 also I know that each of queries takes much time, I mean, I need one query, which will contain both previous

Comment: And I suggested such. If you haven’t tried it then how can you know it is slow and a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM 
             (VALUES(1, 'A', 'qwe rty'),(2, 'B', 'qaz wsx'),(3, 'C', 'zxcv asdf'),(4, NULL, 'pl ok')) v (id,c1,c2)) 
UPDATE so_demo
SET col1 = cte.c1, col2 = cte.c2
FROM cte WHERE cte.id = CASE WHEN COALESCE(cc1, 0) <> 0 THEN 1 
                             WHEN COALESCE(cc2, 0) <> 0 THEN 2
                             WHEN COALESCE(cc3, 0) <> 0 THEN 3 
                             ELSE 4 END;
```

By way of explanation, I have put the possible values into a cte assigning them an id in addition to the values.  I can then put the case statement in the where clause generating the necessary id.  Note the use of COALESCE to make the WHENs simpler to read.

Comment: Side note: `CASE` **expression**, not statement. SQL knows no flow control statements at all.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use arrays.

```
UPDATE t1 
       SET (col1,
            col2) = (SELECT x[1],
                            x[2]
                            FROM (SELECT CASE
                                           WHEN cc1 IS NOT NULL
                                                AND cc1 <> 0 THEN
                                             ARRAY['A',
                                                   'qwe rty']
                                           WHEN cc2 IS NOT NULL
                                                AND cc2 <> 0 THEN
                                             ARRAY['B',
                                                   'qzaz wsx']
                                           ...
                                           ELSE
                                             ARRAY[NULL,
                                                   'pl ok']
                                         END) AS x
                                                 (x));
```

But in terms of *runtime* optimization the gain compared to just `UPDATE ... SET col1 = CASE ..., col2 = CASE ...` should be neglectable, if any.